# Kubernetes - how to mount different secret volumes depending on target deployment environment

Tags: kubernetes

I have three environments - QA, Staging, Production.
Each one has its own credentials.properties file

Right now I just have one secret and it's referenced and mounted in my yaml file as follows

```
          - name: identity-service-secret-here-credentials-volume
            mountPath: "/root/.secrets"
.
.
.
      - name: identity-service-secret-here-credentials-volume
        secret:
          secretName: identity-service-secret-here-credentials
```

I want it to do the equivalent of

```
if(env = QA)
  secretName = secret-qa
if(env = Staging)
  secretName = secret-staging
if(env = Prod)
  secretName = secret-prod
```

Comment: I would highly suggest you use Helm for this. The template feature gives you the ability to use `if`, `else` statements and change configs based on default values or values submitted at runtime.

Comment: Separate namespaces or even physically separate clusters per environment would also be a good answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad design (also from a security perspective) to have helm control structures directives to manage deployments across `dev, stage and prod` in one YAML file.

It best to manage distinct k8s objects for respective deployments required in a distinct environment.

It may be necessary to maintain a distinct Secret in each stage of the pipeline or to make modifications to it as it traverses through the pipeline. Also, take care that if you are storing the Secret as JSON or YAML in an SCM, there is some form of encryption to protect the sensitive information may be warranted.

Comment: Interesting can you clarify exactly why it is a bad design choice to use helm control structures? Also by "distinct environment" does a Tiller namespace qualify? Thanks!

Comment: Most of k8s projects still lack management of RBAC and associated security modules. Note that simply installing Tiller into a namespace does not ensure that Tiller can only install into that namespace. A bad implementation of permission grants would mean that Tiller can write and deploy objects across namespaces. In this context and situation, distinct environments would mean a physical separation of environments and not just logical isolation via namespaces.